# How does the A-Record thing works on Tumblr?

Tags: dns, a-records

**First of all**, sorry if I'm not 100% clear, I'm really confused on all of this.

I noticed that you can always use an **A/AAAA DNS Record on Tumblr**, so if you visit (and navigate) blog.something.com/* (where * is anything else) it uses the Tumblr infrastructure and system, but without modifying the URL at all.

**My question is:** I know that you'll have to add a A Record on your domain (on something.com) but: how do they handle the A Record on their side?

Hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use a [wildcard DNS entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) on your DNS server with a wildcard configuration on your web server (for example, a [wildcard ServerAlias on apache](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache%20wildcard%20serveralias)).